# Eww, a bug. Squish! Wait, should I have not done that?

Tags: halal-haram, animals

*Question*: Is it okay to kill bugs (e.g. spiders, mosquitoes)?  And under what circumstances?

[image: May the curse of Allah be on the one who treats an animal harshly. -- Prophet Muhammad]

(Image source: http://www.think-deep.org/values/treatment-of-animals-according-to-prophet-of-islam)

I feel like I should be more careful when squishing bugs in the future, and try to avoid it if possible (just in case).  However, honestly, I do not value the life of a mosquito the way I value the life of a mammal.

Googling the question leads to some unreliable and/or incomplete answers.  The general attitude is that it's okay if the bugs are harmful or potentially harmful.  However, this is a matter of perspective: any animal could potentially be harmful, e.g., by carrying a disease (although it's the disease which is harmful, not the animal), and it's not like I would investigate.

A mosquito would typically cause momentary discomfort, and maybe an itchy bite.  But if it's diseased, it's a different matter altogether.  In the case of spiders, am I supposed to know which kinds of spiders are poisonous or not?

---

And just for fun, I saw this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/islam/comments/32klpq/is_killing_insects_a_sin/?st=is2jbt7e&sh=05b3bd13) in response to the related question:

> Whenever someone talks about Islam being a violent religion I'm going to point them to this thread about literally not harming a fly.